# Cannot assign requested address system error 99 when trying to startup YugabyteDB

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

I’m trying to startup but I’m getting the following error:
Getting

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-29-115:~/yugabyte-2.7.1.1/new/yb-data/master/logs$ cat yb-master.FATAL.details.2021-11-09T02_55_26.pid18618.txt
F20211109 02:55:26 ../../src/yb/master/master_main.cc:128] Network error (yb/util/net/socket.cc:334): Error binding socket to 35.75.22.184:7100: Cannot assign requested address (system error 99)
    @     0x7fe9f4a2b3cc  yb::LogFatalHandlerSink::send()
    @     0x7fe9f3c128de  google::LogMessage::SendToLog()
    @     0x7fe9f3c0fa6a  google::LogMessage::Flush()
    @     0x7fe9f3c13159  google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()
    @           0x409931  yb::master::MasterMain()
    @     0x7fe9ef803825  __libc_start_main
    @           0x408949  _start
    @              (nil)  (unknown)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error `EADDRNOTAVAIL` means error: `address not available`, and means the master process tried to create a network socket on the ip address set, and didn't find this ip address assigned to any of the ip stacks (set ip addresses) available.

Looking at the address, this is a public ip address, whilst usually the ip addresses in the cloud have private ip addresses (RFC: 1918), and get a public ip address assigned via an internet gateway.

See https://blog.yugabyte.com/yugabyte-db-1-1-new-feature-public-ips-to-simplify-multi-or-hybrid-cloud-database-deployments/ if you need nodes to contact the others through the public network, but you just need to put private IPs.